# elementary os opens tty terminal at start

Tags: release-loki

I have a serious issue that I don't understand. When I start my computer elementary won't open the graphical window to log in and instead it starts a tty terminal. To get the graphical login window I have to login in the tty and run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start
```

Sometimes it takes a few minutes (about 2min max) before it shows the dock and the menu-bar.

I didn't do anything to have this problem. Just some regular updates...

**Update** : thanks to @bigbang it's resolved by running this command :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Comment: Could you try to enter in terminal: dpkg-reconfigure lightdm? What results in typing "cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager" in terminal?

Comment: When i run dpkg-reconfigure lightdm I have this output : ** insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S01shm_load
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `lightdm' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `lightdm' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).**

And when I run cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager I have :
**/usr/sbin/lightdm**

Comment: I created my suggestions as an answer, please mark the answer as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resolve the problem by typing:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Perhaps there is a confusion between display managers. To show the current one, type:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

For other solutions, you have to investigate further.